# Hardcoded link stuck in navigation magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I can't find the exact code I used, all I know is I put some code in a cms block and also wrote the link to the block in top.phtml and topmenu.phtml in both rwd and base.

I've gone through all these files and deleted the link, also deleted the cms block but the link is still there!

Can you guy's help? maybe take a look at the site? its the little "blog" link stuck under the top navigation menu!

https://www.eurgold.eu

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To find the template file for that link, you will need to turn on template path hints.

1. Log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or
   store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a
   new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
   hints.

[Source](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12659-How-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento)

Template path hints are little tags which would lie on top of your shop frontend. These little tags enable you to view where exactly the code of a specific element is stored within your file structure.